# How do I mount a "DiskSecure Multiboot" partition?

Tags: partitioning, mount

For a hard drive that has 4 or 5 partitions, I was able to mount one of them using Ubuntu LiveCD:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

but is there a way to mount to the other partitions?

(if using `sudo fdisk -l`, it only shows `/dev/sda`)

GParted's snapshot is:

[image]

Right now, the `fdisk` info is as follows:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x1aca8ea5

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1       284993226   350602558    32804666+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

and then

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/mnt$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda1

Disk /dev/sda1: 33.6 GB, 33591978496 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 4083 cylinders, total 65609333 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x2052474d

This doesn't look like a partition table
Probably you selected the wrong device.

     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1p1   ?     6579571  1924427647   958924038+  70  DiskSecure Multi-Boot
/dev/sda1p2   ?  1953251627  3771827541   909287957+  43  Unknown
/dev/sda1p3   ?   225735265   225735274           5   72  Unknown
/dev/sda1p4      2642411520  2642463409       25945    0  Empty

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

Per @lgarzo's request, `parted` info is:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/mnt$ sudo parted /dev/sda print
Model: ATA ST3320820AS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 320GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start  End    Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      146GB  180GB  33.6GB  primary  ntfs         boot
```

The command

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1p2 /mnt
```

won't work.

Comment: Its looks like your partition table is corrupted. how is the disk structure showing in gparted? (install it if you haven't)

Comment: Does your HDD contain dynamic disk partitions? A MBR disk can at most contain 4 primary partitions, any further attempt to create a primary partition will result in dynamic disks in Windows, if you don't make the 5th partition extended.

Comment: Alternatively could you include the output of `sudo parted /dev/sda print` in your question?

Comment: @Web-E GParted's snapshot is added to the original post...

Comment: @lgarzo the info is added to the original post

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**
[Samik](https://askubuntu.com/users/27559/samik) kindly added the following observation, that practically „defuses” the reference to the DiskSecure partition:

> I just want to add that I've found the same result i.e. existence of a
>   DiskSecure Multi-boot partition after applying `sudo fdisk -l` on one of
>   my healthy NTFS logical partition. Even the [pattern of result](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1059000/) matches
>   exactly. So I think **it may be some quirks in `fdisk`.**

---

How did you get the „DiskSecure” partition?

According to the documentation of DiskSecure:

> Simply put, DISKSECURE II **replaces the Master Boot Record on a hard
>   disk with its own code**.  The necessary elements of the original
>   partition table are stored on an unused part of the disk and presented
>   to the authenticated operating system as required. Unauthorized boot 
>   programs (such as the BRAIN, STONED, or AZUSA viruses) will not be
>   able to access the partition table as expected.

For more information see this [review](http://freesoft.cyberside.net.ee/FreeSoft/antivir.htm#disksecure).

The DiskSecure utility can be downloaded from [a backup of ftp.simtel.net](http://ftp.freenet.de/pub/ftp.simtel.net/pub/simtelnet/msdos/virus/ds242.zip). (It was considered a virus counter-measure at that time.)

**Note:**
Since this utility was created back in 1994, I *seriously doubt* that you have this installed on your HDD. However the name suggests a reference to it. Anyhow *I do not suggest to install or run* any component from the referenced archive.

Comment: @Samik included your comment in the answer, so that my assumptions seem to be *completely off*. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, hope that helps OP.

Answer (score 1):

There are no partitions. They are an attempt by fdisk to read partition info where there is none - there's just data there being misinterpreted instead. Data may have been copied to a disk that was formatted but not ever partitioned.

To mount entired non-partitioned disk:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/test
sudo chmod 755 /mnt/test
mount -t ntfs /dev/sda /mnt/test
```

(NOT: `mount -t ntfs /dev/sda1 /mnt/test`)

Answer (score 0):

If you have come so far as you see Bootsecure II
Probably by using mkfs.ntfs /dev/sda x 
where value of x is sectors. found using blockdev --getsz

This can be achieved with using fdisk then s for sun partition.

Then you just change the cluster up to a max of 104756 with x value.

and format with mkfs.ntfs max sectors with -F on a valid non hacked system.
as using mkfs.ntfs /dev/sda !set value of blockdev! !important sda! -F -H 255 -S 63 -p 0

Then you simply use sudo fdisk /dev/sda1
set to g as partition gtp.
and delete partition or set a new one with n and push w
then youre SSD of value 250gb might see 6.2TB

Now use you magic

set new partitions one with value 1G making 512GB
next with 2G with 1TB
Second will be set as 4.6TB automatic.

Now use sudo mkfs.ntfs /dev/tty10 1073735000 -H 255 -S 63 -p 2048 -F
then when format is done... after several hours.

sudo mkfs.ntfs /dev/tty11 3221220000 -p 1073743872 -H 255 -S 63 -F

set 3221220000 as value with 5000 less on last fdisk for second drive sectors
value p a little higher.

last format will go like this:
sudo mkfs.ntfs /dev/tty12 9188240000 -p 4294970295 -H 255 -S 63 -F

look at the drive led... kinda strange wouldn't it be?...